# Dashboard Graph delay in update

Tags: magento-1.7, dashboard

There is about a 3 hour delay in the update of our dashboard graph. I have tried clearing cache and disabling cache but the dashboard stats graph doesn't seem to update as frequently as it use to.

Can I keep the graph current?

Comment: What setting do you have in System -> Config -> Sales -> Dashboard -> Use Aggregated Data

Comment: This is set to "no".

This may not be a cache issue, maybe a timezone issue? Whenever I print magento time in the admin it shows 4 hours behind the time that it actually is where I am. Any guidance, please?